# Specifically define an object in my function

Tags: actionscript-3

Do you know if it’s possible to define specifically what is “thisThing” in a function ?

Exemple :
In my UseBox.as

```
        public function UseBox(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:Object){
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            this.thisThing = thisThing;

public function destroy(e:MouseEvent):void{
thisThing.visible = false;
if (thisThing(“HOUSE”)){
doThis();
}
if (thisThing(“FLAT”)){
doThat();
}
```

“HOUSE” and “FLAT” are movieclips.

For now, if I click on a movieclip, it's becoming invisble. I'd like to know if I can define a unique function for a specifically movieclip with the occurrences "house" and "flat".

Thank you for yours answers

---

**EDIT**

Here's the function in my Engine.as where the useBox is called :

```
private function examine(e:MouseEvent):void{
                stage.dispatchEvent(new Event("itemClicked"));
                    useBox = new UseBox(stage, e.currentTarget);
                    useBox.x = mouseX;
                    useBox.y = mouseY;
                    stage.addChild(useBox);
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may create a base class for house and flat, and the base class contains a function which could be called in destroy. The thisThing'type will be the base class type.

Class define

```
//the base class   
public class BaseMc extends MovieClip 
{

      public function onDestroy():void
      {


      }
}

//House
public class House extends BaseMc 
{

      override public function onDestroy():void
      {

           //do the house destroy
      }
}
```

And the UseBox class be will like this

```
public function UseBox(stageRef:Stage, thisThing:BaseMc ){
     this.stageRef = stageRef;
     this.thisThing = thisThing;
}

public function destroy(e:MouseEvent):void{
     thisThing.visible = false;

     this.thisThing.onDestroy();
}
```

**EDIT**

```
useBox = new UseBox(stage, e.currentTarget as Engine);
```

Comment: I've got the error 1020 : Method marked override must override another method. Do you know why ?

Comment: Have you define onDestroy function in BaseMc?

Comment: Forgot that. Done. But now an error in my Engine.as... with the line useBox = new UseBox(stage,e.currentTarget); that is suppose to create the UseBox where I can click on destroy (and call the function "destroy". The error is 1067: Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca:Engine vers un type sans rapport com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca:BaseMc.

Comment: I've eddited my original post to show you the function in Engine.as that is causing the error.

Comment: Your engine class should be the subclass of BaseMc, like house mentioned.

Comment: Don't know why, but I've still got an error (1118: Contrainte implicite d'une valeur du type statique Object vers un type peut-être sans rapport com.laserdragonuniversity.alpaca:Engine.) And it's still the line useBox = new UseBox(stage, e.currentTarget);  I've follow everything you said, except I named BaseMc "Engine", and add the function onDestroy in it (and, of course, I've replaced every "BaseMc" you've mentionned by "Engine")